# Do I Need a Workgroup File for Access 2007 Backend?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I know I used to need these things when (once upon a time) I was an Access developer (Access 97), but do I need a workgroup file to share a backend database with two other users?

I did the split database thing and gave each their own copy of the front-end, and I thought that simply putting the backend part on a shared file location would do it.

The others can read the database and run forms and such, but they can't add rows - I still can.

What am I missing?

Comment: If your Access 2007 db file is ACCDB format, user level security is not supported, so this is not a workgroup file issue.  Check first whether the other users have read-write permissions for the folder where the db file is stored.

Comment: They do have rw permission to the folder (and the .accdb file too).  The docs say something about User Permissions.. is that only for old(er) versions or something?

Comment: ULS (Jet user level security) is only supported with the older MDB format.  I don't know what's going on in your situation.  Are those users perhaps opening the db in read-only mode?  Can they edit anything?

Comment: Can those users open the BE accdb directly (not from the FE) and be able to edit (update, insert, delete)?  What permissions do they have on the folder where their FE copies are stored?

Comment: They can.. I'm doing edits in VBA attached to forms they are using.. I bet some defaults are biting me.. Thanks for the diagnostic help..  I'll re-reply if that doesn't work.